# A draggable/resizable div with iframe child that stretches to parent with some padding/margin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, size

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nEzfQ/

The iframe should stretch to the parent div size with some padding or margin.. what's wrong with this?

```
<div class="outer ui-widget-content">
    <iframe src="about:blank"></iframe>
</div>

iframe {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background-color: green;
}

.outer {
    top: 20px;
    left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve: parent div that acts as a frame/border that can be used to drag/resize the iframe..

Caveat: I need the size of the outer div to be the real size, no padding or margin to it.

Comment: So, you want the iframe to change size as the outer div is resized?

Comment: Yes, but even at start it should be positioned/sized correctly, e.g. within a 20px margin from the outer div

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me why you have the `ui-widget-content` class on the outer div? Do you need it there? It's causing part of the problem.

Comment: I do not need it, it adds a nice border

Comment: Something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/2dUGz/1/

Comment: indeed, but with a fixed distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/nEzfQ/5/)

**With Output**

```
$("#outerdims").val(JSON.stringify({
    height: $(".outer").height(),
    width: $(".outer").outerWidth(true)
}));
$("#iframedims").val(JSON.stringify({
    height: $("iframe").height(),
    width: $("iframe").outerWidth(true)
}));
$(".outer").resizable({
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        var newWd = ui.size.width - 20;
        var newHt = ui.size.height - 20;
        $("iframe").width(newWd).height(newHt);
        $("#outerdims").val(JSON.stringify({
            height: $(".outer").height(),
            width: $(".outer").outerWidth(true)
        }));
        $("#iframedims").val(JSON.stringify({
            height: $("iframe").height(),
            width: $("iframe").outerWidth(true)
        }));
    }
}).draggable();
```

**Without Output**

```
$(".outer").resizable({
    resize: function (event, ui) {
        var newWd = ui.size.width - 20;
        var newHt = ui.size.height - 20;
        $("iframe").width(newWd).height(newHt);
    }
}).draggable();
```

Comment: Obviously, 80% of this script is updating the values of the inputs just so I could see what was going on. I'll give you both versions.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution (I did something similar after the answer of @Amenadiel - http://jsfiddle.net/nEzfQ/3/): a small thing still bothers me: if you try to resize "back" shrinking the iframe, you loose the focus on the resize.. is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Let me see what happens when I change the `stop` event to the `resize` event. Ok, that works pretty well. There's a tad bit of lag but that's just intrinsic of the widgets themselves.

Comment: Yes, indeed :) If you are too fast and the cursors goes over the green area of the iframe you loose the resize.. oh well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can actually achieve this with CSS only. I suggest you try a walkaround using JS listener over the resizable element.

```
$("#container").resizable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $("#dim").text(JSON.stringify(ui.size));
        $("#myiframe").width(ui.size.width).height(ui.size.height);

    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nEzfQ/1/

Comment: You forgot to update the fiddle.. either way, that could be a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nEzfQ/3/

not really what I was looking for.. I was hoping in a css/less hacky solution.. 

a problem though: if I resize back "too fast" the cursor goes over the iframe and loses the resize.. is there a workaround?